# Why does gRPC uses Length Prefixed Messages?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, http2, grpc-java

I am trying to understand how does gRPC sends stream messages using HTTP2 ? The link https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/PROTOCOL-HTTP2.md says,

***"The repeated sequence of Length-Prefixed-Message items is delivered in DATA frames"***

My understanding from reading this statement is that each (protobuf) message is encapsulated by gRPC in a HTTP2 Data Frame and sent over. If thats so, then why do gRPC need to append Length Prefix to the message, can't it simply read the complete Data Frame Body and assume it to be one complete message ?

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Completely guessing here, bit I would *presume* that this is so that in streaming mode (not unary mode, i.e. `stream` in the protobuf DSL), and when buffering is enabled (write-options), multiple data element may be delivered in a single HTTP/2 data frame.

Comment: Also, the doc you linked states "DATA frame boundaries have no relation to Length-Prefixed-Message boundaries and implementations should make no assumptions about their alignment."- this suggests that even a single data message could end up split over multiple HTTP/2 data frames of it decides so.

Comment: Thanks that explains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing part is that there is not guarantee that one DATA frame contains only one gRPC message. gRPC messages is a higher layer stream that works as payload for HTTP/2. It may be implemented in the way you described in the official gRPC libraries, but in terms of protocol it is totally valid to receive some DATA frame with more than one gRPC PDU.